# COBOLのゼロサプレスの仕様

Tags: cobol

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. CALC.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
  01 TESTCALCARRAY.
    03 TESTVAR OCCURS 5 PIC 9(5) VALUE 0.
  01 TESTDISPARRAY.
    03 TESTDISP OCCURS 5 PIC ZZZZ9.
  01 SUMVAR PIC 99999 VALUE 0.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
  MAIN SECTION.
  ADD 5 TO TESTVAR(1) TESTVAR(2) TESTVAR(3) TESTVAR(4) TESTVAR(5).
  SUBTRACT 1 FROM  TESTVAR(2).
  DIVIDE  TESTVAR(1) BY 3 GIVING  TESTVAR(4) REMAINDER  TESTVAR(3).
  MULTIPLY TESTVAR(1) BY 0 GIVING  TESTVAR(5).
  COMPUTE SUMVAR = TESTVAR(1)+TESTVAR(2)+TESTVAR(3)+TESTVAR(4)+TESTVAR(5)
  DISPLAY TESTCALCARRAY.
  DISPLAY SUMVAR.
  MOVE TESTCALCARRAY TO TESTDISPARRAY.
  DISPLAY TESTDISPARRAY.
  STOP RUN.
```

このようなコードを書いたのですが、
最後のDISPLAY TESTDISPARRAYが

```
0000500004000020000100000
```

となってしまいます。

```
□□□□5□□□□4□□□□2□□□□1□□□□0
```

となる想定なのですが、どの部分が違っているでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WORKING-STORAGE SECTION`の`01`のところは[集団項目](http://itdoc.hitachi.co.jp/manuals/3020/3020378270/LANG0075.HTM)ですので、`PIC`句は[利用不可](http://www.csis.ul.ie/cobol/course/DataDeclaration.htm#part3)みたいです。そのために、集団項目を`DISPLAY`してみると、集団項目は内側のレベル番号の`PIC`句のフォーマティングまで読めないのだと私は思っています。

一方で、内側のレベル番号を独立的に`DISPLAY`してみると、`PIC`句のフォーマティングが表示されるみたいですね。例えば、`DISPLAY TESTDISP(1)`

それでは、`PIC`句のフォーマティングを保存するために、繰り返し文を[使う](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cobol/try_cobol.php)のはどうですか。

コード例：

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. EXAMPLE.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
  01 TESTCALCARRAY.
    03 TESTVAR OCCURS 3 PIC 9(5) VALUE 0.
  01 TESTDISPARRAY.
    03 TESTDISP OCCURS 3 PIC ZZZZ9.
  01 C PIC 99 VALUE 1.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
  MAIN SECTION.
  ADD 1 TO TESTVAR(1)
  ADD 2 TO TESTVAR(2)
  ADD 3 TO TESTVAR(3)
  PERFORM EXAMPLE-LOOP UNTIL C>3.
  STOP RUN.

  EXAMPLE-LOOP.
  MOVE TESTVAR(C) TO TESTDISP(C).
  DISPLAY TESTDISP(C) WITH NO ADVANCING.
  ADD 1 TO C.
```

コードの結果：

```
    1    2    3
```